# Audio assigned to a mouse click doesn't work, as the clickable image is h ref link

Tags: php, image, click, href, event-listener

I have assigned audio to a mouse click and it doesn't work. Clickable image is h ref link and I guess it's a reason. Could you advise me on how to correct syntax, to make it work?

Here is the code in JavaScript:

```
document.querySelector(".title-image").addEventListener("click", function() {

  var audio = new Audio("sounds/birds-sounds.mp3");
      audio.play();

});
```

Code in HTML:

```
<a href="?????????.html">
              <img class="title-image" src="images/??????????.jpg" alt="????????">
            </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need "a" tag here. You can remove the <a...> and just keep the img tag.

You can use CSS to add pointer on the image.

```
<style>
    .title-image
    {
        cursor: pointer;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I need <a...>, because image is linked to the another html page. If I remove <a...>, then clicking the image, won't redirect to html page.

Comment: You can add the redirection with javascript. After playing the audio.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_redirect_webpage.asp details here

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution:

```
<a onClick="return playAudio();" href="?????????.html">
    <img class="title-image" src="images/??????????.jpg" alt="????????">
</a>

<script>   
function playAudio() {
    var audio = new Audio("sounds/birds-sounds.mp3");
    audio.play();
 
    return true;
}   
</script>
```